# how to get array using $.ajax in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have page getorgname.php which return array so how do i get the array in my jquery page using $.ajax method?

```
$ds = my_ldap_connect(CHI_LDAP_LOCATION, CHI_LDAP_PORT, CHI_LDAP_USE_TLS);
$groups = get_all_groups($ds, CHI_LDAP_BASE_DN, CHI_LDAP_BIND_DIRECTORY, CHI_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD);
$sr = @ldap_search($ds, "ou=people,".CHI_LDAP_BASE_DN, "(uid=*)");
$nt = ldap_get_entries( $ds, $sr );
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($nt);
//echo "</pre>";
foreach( $nt as $each )
{
    if( is_array( $each ) )
    {

        $json[] = trim('"'.$each['o'][0].'"');

    }
}
```

return $json;

Answer (score 2):

Set the proper json headers to serve json and print the array in json format:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

//create your array here

echo json_encode(array);
```

Then receive the array on the client side using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'getorgname.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
       //the 'data' object contains your array
       //do stuff with it here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without setting the data-type in jQ's `$.ajax` call, and by simply using the `echo` construct rather then `return`, you should be fine. If you start messing with the headers, chances are you'll run into trouble sooner or later: 
You can only set the headers if no output has been generated yet, so be weary: either buffer, or keep the `header` calls at the very top. Just *know what you're doing*.

In your case just ending in `echo json_encode($json);` will do the trick:

```
foreach( $nt as $each )
{
    if( is_array( $each ) )
    {
        $json[] = trim($each['o'][0]);
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

That's all you need to do, you don't have to format the JSON manually.
Your jQ should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourscript.php',
    data: yourRequestObject,
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);//this'll be either an array or an object (assoc array's are objects in JS)
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget `dataType: "json"` to avoid issues if jQuery fails to detect that it's json and not plain text.

Comment: @KevinB: Well, 9 out of 10 jQuery's _"educated guess"_ is correct (I haven't seen it go wrong once). That said, I haven't used jQuery in over a year now... :)